# ASP.NET CORE Don't have app.UseEndpoints() Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr

Just learning ASP.NET Core now and in some guides I see app.UseEndpoints() method.

But when I created my ASP NET CORE Project I've only seen app.Run in StartUp.cs

1. So Need I install some utilities for this or UseEndPoints was removed?
2. How Can I realize this method
    `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chat"); });`

Comment: Which .net core version are you using?

Comment: You can find answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61404058/asp-net-core-dont-have-app-useendpoints-method/61404819#61404819

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Net Core 2.1, you have to configure it that way:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using SignalRChat.Hubs;

namespace SignalRChat
{


public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddSignalR();
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chat");
        });
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}

}
```

Only afrer version 3.0 you can use `app.UseEndpoints`

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {              
            endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chat");
        });
```

See docs:

[ASP.NET Core 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?tabs=visual-studio&view=aspnetcore-2.1)

[ASP.NET Core 3.0 +](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?tabs=visual-studio&view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET Core 3.1 version, then you need to make sure you've got:

`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;`

In the file, and you'll need to be referencing (directly or indirectly) the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing` assembly.

Comment: I use .NET Core 2.1 and I have the Builder using in project but it isn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you are learning, you are better off starting with current .NET Core version, which is 3.1. 2.1 didn't have endpoint routing at all, work towards endpoint routing started in 2.2 but I think it was mostly behind the scenes, not exposed to consumer code as `UseEndpoints()`. In 3.1, Sean's answer applies - you usually get the correct NuGet include just by specifying `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` in your csproj.